# Как подсчитывать кол-во участников, эмодзи и каналов со всех серверов на которых состоит бот? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

Как это реализовать, так чтобы оно ещё и обновлялось при добавлении эмодзи, людей, и каналов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получаем список всех серверов, где есть бот: `bot.guilds`

Получаем список участников конкретного сервера: `guild.members`

Получаем список эмоджи сервера: `guild.emojis`

Получаем список каналов сервера: `guild.channels`

---

Проверить, `голосовой` канал или `текстовый` можно через его атрибут `type`.

Текстовый канал - `discord.ChannelType.text`, Голосовой - `discord.ChannelType.voice`

---

Получить информацию о создании нового канала можно при помощи события [`on_guild_channel_create(channel)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_guild_channel_create#discord.on_guild_channel_create)

Получить информацию о подключении нового участника можно при помощи события [`on_member_join(member)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_member_join#discord.on_member_join)

Получить информацию о создании нового emoji вроде бы как нельзя...

---

**Далее выводим список нужно инфы через цикл `for`**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    number = 0
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        number += 1
        print(f'{number}. {guild.name}')
        
        print('Участники:')
        for member in guild.members:
            print(f'    {member.name}')

        print('Каналы:')
        voice = []; text = []
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if channel.type != discord.ChannelType.category:
                if channel.type == discord.ChannelType.text: text.append(channel)
                if channel.type == discord.ChannelType.voice: voice.append(channel)
        print(' Текстовые:')
        for channel in text:
            print(f'        {channel}')
        print(' Голосовые:')
        for channel in voice:
            print(f'        {channel}')

        print('Эмоджи:')
        for emoji in guild.emojis:
            print(f'    {emoji.name}')
        
        print(f'\n{"="*60}\n')


@bot.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    print(f'На сервере {channel.guild} создали новый канал: {channel.name}')

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'На сервер {member.guild} зашел новый пользователь: {member.name}')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

**Не забудьте указать токен!**

Comment: Большое вам спасибо)